Telethon message request sometimes returns empty message's raw_text, text and message attributes
I read telegram channel messages:
channel = await self.client.get_entity(entity)
messages = await self.client.get_messages(channel, limit=lim)

text_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
    'channel_id',
    'message_id',
    'message_text',
    'message_datetime'
])

for x in messages:
    
    message_list = list(range(4))
    
    message_list[0] = int(tg_channel[0])
    message_list[1] = int(x.id)
    message_list[2] = str(x.raw_text) #str(x.message)
    message_list[3] = str(x.date)
    
    text_df.loc[len(text_df)] = message_list
    
    print(len(x.raw_text))
    print(len(x.text))
    print(len(x.message))
    print('\n ############# \n')

It is not expected that on the same channel I may get 1 message containing text, and 4 other without text. I tried manual checking of those messages in telegram, and all I found is that messages with video content attached, but text below, do not return texts, but I am not sure if this is a 100% chance. I also saw messages with photos attached sometimes do not return text. I was getting the same outcome for message.raw_text, message.text, and message.message, example is below.

Trying to get messages for  https://t.me/DtRoad
0 0 0
#############
0 0 0
#############
0 0 0
#############
1011 1068 1011
#############
953 1019 953
#############
Got 5 messages

Two of them contain non-empty text content only.
What factor could affect the absence of the text?
Edit as of 18 december 2024.

Trying to get messages for  https://t.me/bpshkola
0 0 0
#############
Got 1 messages

I got again an empty text, and immediately checked the telegram message

So it has text/captions and some pictures. It is still not clear why I get no text of that message.

Messages with media and without captions, or service messages, do not have text.

first of all, thank you for reaching out. I should say the messages in question have both text and video/pics. I parse news channels, so what I saw were definitely messages with captions. I think the issue is more nontrivial. I researched it for several days, getting flooding errors as well, and then instead of the limit I added offset_date and reverse (n minutes between parser starts). So I am getting about 10 times less messages, but their timestamp is always good, and empty message count went to zero, I think now that the returned emptiness somehow connected with getting too many of them.
